# Hiding divs without a class within a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a set of divs with a variety of classes and a set of selects which will hide the appropriate items

I'm using

```
if($(this).val() == "venta"){
    $(".results").not('.venta').hide();

}
```

but my problem is that I thought this would only change items inside the .results div - but of course it makes the whole page vanish. So I've tried to figure out how to make it only divs that are a child of the `<div class="results">` but just can't get something that works.

Comment: [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Comment: Need more information.  If we could see the HTML that would help

Comment: Do you want the `.venta` elements hidden, or everything _but_ the `.venta` elements hidden?

Comment: $(".results").children().not('.venta').hide();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.not('.venta')` selector applies to the `.results` elements you selected. Try something like this:

```
$(".results").children().not('.venta').hide();
```

or

```
$('.results').children(':not(.venta)').hide();
```

Comment: Yeah first one did it - I'd tried something similar that didn't work, I must've just had it slightly wrong - thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".results").find(".venta").hide();
```